# languages parsed with recursive descent

Tags: recursion, context-free-grammar, recursive-descent

I was wondering what makes languages possible to be parsed with recursive descent. for example we have 5 languages over {x,y,r}:

```
A = { x^n y^n | n <= k }
B = { x^n y^k | n > k }
C = { x^k y^n | k > n }
D = { x^n y^n r^n | n <= k }
E = { x^n y^n r^n | n >= k }
```

where there are n occurences of x,y,r and k is unknown.

My reasoning is that only if we can define the language with a context free grammar then it can be parsed with recursive descent and if that is the case I think only B and C are possible to be parsed with recursive decent but I am not sure

Comment: This is the same question as https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/160242/which-language-can-be-parsed-recursive-descent so I guess it is a class assignment!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for L1, it is possible to parse in recursive descent as it would be possible to recognise for a DPDA.

Comment: that is true, but arent B and C also possible to parse with recursive descent?

Comment: I am not quite sure, I believe it is difficult to create an LL grammar for these languages

Comment: ommästar?@yes12345

Comment: Have you figured it out yet?